# How to migrate from uTorrent to BitComet

Tags: utorrent

I've been using uTorrent for long time, I have a lot of files for seeding to keep my rates. Now I want to use BitComet client because it looks better for me.

The problem is that how to move all these torrent files to BitComet. In google there are some notes about this issue, but what they actually telling is how to migrate one file per step. For me it's very long time, is there some possibility to migrate in short way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm going to go ahead and say that nobody have ever, or will bother, two write a uTorrent to BitComet import utility.

You'll have to do the standard thing: open the torrents in BitComet, and point the download location to where the complete file already is.

BitComet will verify you have the file complete and start seeding.